# Any idea how to write code that can be easily ported to iphone, android and blackberry?

Tags: iphone, android

I'm looking for a way to easily port content driven applications from one mobile platform to another. Currently HTML5+js seems to be the only language that can be easily reused.

Can you share your experience? I'm looking for a way to go forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Titanium Mobile?

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

You can build apps for iPhone/iPad & Android using JavaScript - doesn't support blackberry (yet), though.

Comment: The hello world app crashes on the iphone simulator. (I was using official build of the Titanium). Have you used it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. HTML5+CSS+JavaScript is a viable and recommended solution for cross-platform mobile apps. If you're already familiar with these technologies there is no reason for you to learn a new one (such as Titanium Mobile as was suggested by someone else).

Comment: Something like Phonegap, which is an abstraction layer library underneath your HTML/Javascript, may help your web app code be more portable cross-platforms.

Comment: @hotpaw2 why not add the "Phonegap" as an answer so user can vote it up?